# Listing elements without manually specifying them

Tags: python, list, range

I'm attempting to turn the old, "roll dice" program into something more different. I would like to add more numbers instead of 6, but typing all the numbers out seems painstaking. I'm sure you programmers have an easier way to do things like this.

Example:

```
hist = pygal.Bar()

    hist.title = "Results of rolling numbers 0-69 100 times."
    hist.x_labels = ['1', '2', '3']
    hist.x_title = "Numbers Rolled"
    hist.y_title = "Frequency of numbers rolled"
```

On line 3, I want to be able to insert numbers 1-69, or even more if i wish to change it. How can I do this easily?

I thought the range() function would work, but it didn't, unless I'm doing something wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list and a simple for loop, e.g.

```
numbers = []
for number in range(100):
    numbers.append(number)
```

this will give you a list with all values from 0 -> 100.

as John Gordon pointed out it seems you may want to have those numbers as Strings, for that just change the third line to:

```
numbers.append(str(number))
```

Comment: I assume his issue with `range()` is that it produces integers, not strings as in his example.

Comment: yeah, just realized that he had the values as strings in his list aswell.

Answer (score 2):

`range()` will work, but you have to convert each value to a string instead of an integer.

```
hist.x_labels = [ str(n) for n in range(69) ]
```